# O que está errado no meu código? (problema 1805 da URI)

Tags: c

Estou tentando resolver a questão 1805 da URI:

> Um número natural é um inteiro não-negativo (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...). A sua tarefa neste problema é calcular a soma dos números naturais que estão presentes em um determinado intervalo [**A**, **B**] inclusive.
>
> Por exemplo, a soma dos números naturais no intervalo [2, 5] é 14 = (2+3+4+5).
>
> ## Entrada
>
> Cada caso de teste contém dois inteiros **A** e **B** (1 ≤ **A** ≤ **B** ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>), representando o limite inferior e o superior respectivamente.
>
> ## Saída
>
> Para cada caso de teste, a saída consiste de uma linha contendo a soma dos números naturais do intervalo.

Mas sempre está dando erro:

> [image: Time limit exceeded]

Não sei o que está errado sendo que os resultados são iguais que a questão.

O código é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    long long int n1,n2,i,j=0;
    scanf("%lld %lld",&n1,&n2);
    for(i=n1;i<=n2;i++)
    {
        j+=i;
    }
    printf("%lld\n",j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595

Comment: Enunciado do problema: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1805

Comment: Como você é um usuário iniciante e o código é simples, quebrei o galho e postei o código como texto na pergunta para você. Entretanto, evite postar código como imagem.

Comment: @vnbrs Entendo você colocar que é erro de timeout no título, mas acho que a informação de que isso é um erro de timeout faz parte da resposta, ainda mais considerando que o autor da pergunta enfatiza "*que os resultados são iguais que a questão*", mas nada havia falado sobre o tempo.

Comment: tudo bem,com o tempo vou me aprendendo com o tempo,obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 3):

O código em si está correto, mas ele tem um desempenho muito ruim.

Tal [como está no enunciado](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1805):

> ## Entrada
>
> Cada caso de teste contém dois inteiros **A** e **B** (1 ≤ **A** ≤ **B** ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>), representando o limite inferior e o superior respectivamente.

Ou seja, se a entrada for a seguinte:

> ```
> 1 1000000000
> ```

O seu programa vai demorar um longo tempo para terminar. E é aí que ele estoura o tempo limite. A solução é procurar uma solução baseada em [progressão aritmética](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica) que elimine a necessidade de utilizar-se o laço `for`, fornecendo o resultado em um tempo rápido independente de qual for a entrada utilizada.

Comment: Outros detalhes: 10^9 não necessita de `long long int` , como em um inteiro de 32 bits (normalmente `int`, mas às vezes em plataformas mais antigas `long int`).

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Lembre que ele ainda vai somar todos esses fatores. O resultado é que no caso de 1 até 10^9, a soma é de 500.000.000.500.000.000, o que estoura um inteiro de 32 bits.

Comment: bem percebido. Eu me preocupei só com a entrada, esqueci dos cálculos