# Problema com a questão 2144 da URI

Tags: c

Enunciado: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2144

O código que tenho:

```
{

    double direito,esquerdo,repeticao,e,d,m,c=0;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&esquerdo,&direito,&repeticao);
        if(esquerdo==0&&direito==0&&repeticao==0)
            break;
        d=direito*(1+(repeticao/30));
        e=esquerdo*(1+(repeticao/30));
        m=(d+e)/2;
        c+=m;
        if(m>=1&&m<13)
        {
            printf("Nao vai da nao\n");
        }
        else if(m>=13&&m<14)
        {
            printf("E 13\n");
        }
        else if(m>=14&&m<40)
        {
            printf("Bora, hora do show! BIIR! \n");
        }
        else if(m>=40&&m<=60)
        {
            printf("Ta saindo da jaula o monstro!\n");
        }
        else if(m>60)
        {
            printf("AQUI E BODYBUILDER!!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
        if(c>40)
        {
            printf("Aqui nois constroi fibra rapaz! Nao e agua com musculo!\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tente formatar de modo mais amigável a quem vai ler sua pergunta, como o estado final que ficou essa sua pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251296/64969

Comment: Seu código não tem nada a ver com o enunciado daqui: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2114 - Tem certeza que o número correto é 2114?

Comment: perdão,questão certa 2144

Comment: Pode postar o código completo? Aquele `break;` me faz sugerir que pode haver algo errado com o seu loop.

Comment: Você deveria dividir o `c` por alguma coisa antes do `if` no final. Para saber pelo que seria, teria que ver o seu código todo.

Comment: pronto agora o codigo está completo

Comment: Ainda não está completo porque faltou o `#include <stdio.h> int main(int argc, char**argv)`. Mas isso já foi o suficiente para se produzir uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O [enunciado](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2144) diz:

> No final, se a média de todos os casos for maior do que 40

Você está somando todos os casos, mas não está dividindo pelo número de casos, logo o cálculo da média está errado.

O seu problema é que você tem que contar quantas vezes o código roda no `while`. Use um contador (vamos chamá-lo de `cont`) para isso, declarado antes do `while`. Coloque um `cont++;` na linha após o `break;`.

No final, antes do `if`, faça `if (c != 0) c /= cont;`.

Além disso, veja essa string:

```
"Bora, hora do show! BIIR! \n"
```

Aquele espaço em branco no final vai te causar problemas.

Comment: "Aquele espaço em branco no final pode te causar problemas." ==> o URI considera erro de apresentação, _presentation error_

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Muito obrigado pelo informação. Troquei "pode" por "vai".